# How to know which extension or software is causing ads in Chrome?

Tags: spam, chrome, browser-extensions

Starting yesterday, I noticed that something weird is going on with my laptop. After unlocking my laptop I found that the empty Chrome pages that I opened are getting redirected to ads. I am running Ubuntu and haven't downloaded any specific Chrome extensions recently. What might cause something like this?

[image]

and the URL is this:

```
http://indianews.com-l1jgx3j214ycs1w319vwnrjgqi78cgaug.pw/index2.html?voluumdata=vid..00000001-0fc3-49d6-8000-000000000000__vpid..c5751000-49c0-11e5-87cf-7a8b20f9d13c__caid..20b2f658-3bf0-46c1-beac-920ef0f8c0b3__rt..R__lid..e84c87f6-7600-461e-9f5d-1c4ff52dce63__oid1..e5caf233-f36c-40b7-9b0a-8cadf6a9be48__var1..2440407131440355167__rd..www%5C.%5Cyouradexchange%5C.%5Ccom__aid..__sid..&clk=2440407131440355167
```

I have checked to see whether some script is injected by an extension but I couldn't find any. And the weird thing is, I did search for Facebook Internships. It might be a pure coincidence or I have no idea how this is done.

Comment: Are you certain that it is a chrome extension causing this, and not your OS or router using some bogus DNS to redirect google or facebook to a different server?

Comment: I think you have jumped to the conclusion that it is a Chrome extension.

Comment: From the details you provided, it is technically not "phishing" but simply spam ads. It is very likely that the one posting these ads will pay you to "post links", just as the ad says.

Comment: Check what do you have now at "Starting page", it may have changed. I agree with schroeder, there may be other several reason for this to happen. So disable all plugins, reset starting page and see if it still happening.

Comment: Does this still happen when you browse? Even after you restarted your browser/machine?. For the moment do not log to your private stuff: emails, bank, Facebook

Comment: The startup page is google's default page. That specific add page only loads when the system is locked and chrome has some empty tabs open. I went through all the extensions and deleted the ones I do not use and I do not recognize. I don't think it's because of some virus because I use Ubuntu and I am very careful about what I install. I still haven't been able to detect the cause and I also don't think it's a DNS issue since we are behind a proxy server and my friends are not facing any problems.